# How do I get my Android game's graphics to update?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm struggling right now to figure out the best way to get the graphics to free up in my Android game. Right now, I've tried the following.

- Just start everything in onCreate() -> No graphics appear, because I never leave onCreate().
- Set up a thread - Has problems with dialogs and such, but without dialogs, I can make it work.

So, what should I be doing? I would like to start this when I enter the activity, and require no input to start (There are several inputs during the game, of course), at least, ideally. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having problems with dialogs, you might need to look into runOnUiThread.

Comment: This almost works, except my dialog pops up too late. I need a way to make the thread wait until the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: Ah, that's kind of different from "require no further user input." You could use a looper, and add a new task when the dialog closes. Or you could fire off a new AsyncTask when the dialog closes.

Comment: AsyncTask worked, with a bit of re-organization. Should have thought of that... Sigh. Thanks!